# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview..)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I want to write a good chat application with bottom navigation using Fragments. In ChatsFragment.kt I got a problem: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buB0V.png)

My fun onCreateView() in ChatsFragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    usersRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)

    var userlist = ArrayList<User>()
    userlist.add(User("Squirrel", "https://wampi.ru/image/RjQ3yNw"))
    userlist.add(User("Adam", "https://wampi.ru/image/RjQ3yNw"))


    var userAdapter = UserAdapter(requireActivity(), userlist)
    usersRecycler.adapter = userAdapter
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false)

}
```

Exception on **usersRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)**

I read a lot of solutions like: "replace "this" to requiredActivity() or requiredContext()", but nothing helped, throwing out this error: **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference**

I also wanted replace Fragments on Activity as bottom navigation. Would that be the wrong decision?

How can I resolve this problem? Help me, android developers, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue you need to pass the context of fragment. in Kotlin below code can solve your problem. Just pass "activity"

```
   val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
```

You can also user

```
 layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
```

Both will return the getActivity() instance.

[image: check this]

Please let me know if you still face the error will help you for sure.

Thanks

Comment: How can I use this variable? 
Like this?
```val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
   usersRecycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
```?

Comment: You just need to put context like    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity) only. In kotlin there is no need of variable for that.

Comment: OMG! After a day of trying to solve the problem, it was solved! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In
`onCreateView` method is called when Fragment should create its View object hierarchy, either dynamically or via XML layout inflation.

`onViewCreated` event is triggered soon after onCreateView(). Any view setup should occur here.  E.g., view lookups and attaching view listeners.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Setup any handles to view objects here
    usersRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.rv)
    usersRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
}
```

OR

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false)
    usersRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    usersRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    return view
  }
```

Comment: use of " this " will give you the same error. You can't use this with fragment. You need to get the getActivity() instance.so in kotlin you can either pass "activity" or you can use requireActivity().

Answer (score 0):

userRecycler is not initialized, you need to call

```
RecyclerView userRecycler = findViewById(ID)
```

to solve your issue

Comment: I wrote as follows, but "this" still underlined in red

```val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.usersRecycler)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
```

Comment: can you please pass requireContext() instead of this @КатеринаОстровская

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the RecyclerView

```
val recyclerView: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
```

Also, LinearLayoutManager takes the context in its first argument. "this" points to fragment at that line, not the needed context. You should probably change it to:

```
usersRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
```

Comment: Then why do I need recyclerView? it's not used

Comment: requireContext() will give you the context you need to pass requireActivity() to get the getActivity() context for fragment.